# How can I get process id in WDDM driver

Tags: windows, driver, pid, display

Now I'm programming on the WDDM driver, I want to get the process id of the application which generates the picture. I use the function `psGetCurrentProcessId` but it returns 4 that is the system process, how can I get the real process id?

Comment: How do you send the pictures to your driver? Or is it something like a display mirroring one? 4 is a real process ID, the System process has it. If applications send the pictures utilizing IRPs, you can check for the PID in the dispatch routine (they are usually called in the context of the thread) or via `IoGetRequestorProcessId`

Answer (score 0):

PS:
The WDDM driver is a virtual driver, I use it to maintain pictures and send them to remote clients to display(like RDP). so I must compress the pictures before transmission. When I get the process id of the application, I can compress the pictures belong to the corresponding application to decide compression algorithm in lossy or lossless.